# How to install and upgrade to one clean new version of python and all packages

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I wish to upgrade from pyton `3.9` to `3.10` keeping all the same `pip` packages.
Please advise if the below steps are correct (for `windows10`) or if there is a better method.

**part 1**: generate a `requirements.txt` file

```
pip freeze
```

This produces a list of modules. Save this as `requirements.txt`.

**part 2**: install the new python version `3.10` from the web.

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

If you already have an older version of the same Python release (for example, 3.9.1), the installer offers to upgrade your Python installation. Proceed by selecting **Upgrade Now**.

First question: is `3.9` to `3.10` classified as "*an older version of the same release*" (ie. both version 3) for the purpose of upgrade ?

**Part 3**: install all packages to the new version.

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

Next question: how can one ensure that the requirements.txt are installed to the new version and not reinstalled to the older version ?

**step 4**: remove the old version(s) of python (presumably by *add or remove programs* in windows10 ?)

Comment: You forgot to use the `-r` argument for the installation. It should be `pip install -r requirements.txt`
Moreover, to generate the file, it is easier to do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` which redirects the console display to the file (thanks to the `>` symbol)

Comment: @Brinfer,  thank you. much appreciated.  I was just going to copy the contents of the freeze to a `requirements.txt` file and then save that in a location of my choice.  Which directory would the `>` take the user to ?

Comment: `>` is  the command-line redirection operator and sends the output from the preceding command to the file specified following it. If you upgrade Python, you will not need to uninstall the older version.

Comment: Presumably, for completeness, one should remove the old requirements once new ones are installed?